# Is it possible to turn on detailed verbose errors for android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to turn on detailed verbose errors for android, so that when an application crashes, it gives you the exception that was called?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) project. ACRA is an automatic crash reporting library for Android that lets you configure how to submit the crash reports. The default mechanism is to update a Google Doc, but you can configure it in many other ways.

Comment: This seems a bit intense, is there no way just to feed a crashlog back into whatever IDE your developing with? Or at least read a text file on the device or something like that?

Comment: [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) already does that. In Eclipse, if you have the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) installed, go to DDMS perspective and see the logcat tab. There is option to save the logcat to file.